# PHP anonymous recursive callback call

Tags: php, recursion, callback, anonymous-function

I am having the following class :

```
class MyClass
{
    public $groups = array(
        'callback' => '',
        'name'     => ''
    );

    public function group($callback)
    {
        $this->groups['callback'] = $callback;
        return $this;
    }

    public function name($name)
    {
        $this->groups['name'] .= $name . '/';
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // this callback should keep calling it self till no more callbacks in 
        $this->groups['callback']($this);
    }
}
```

This is what i am trying to achieve.

```
$myclass = new MyClass;

$myclass->group(function($m){ // main group


    $m->group(function($a){ // sub group


        $a->group(function($b){  // 2nd sub group 

            echo 'sub 2'; 

        })->name('sub-2');

        echo 'sub 1';

    })->name('sub-group');


    echo 'group 1';

})->name('group-1');


$myclass->execute();
```

But can't seem to get the sub groups to be called recursively can only get the first level executed which is group 1;

Comment: The problem is that at each level you only declare the callback function, you would need the equivalent of `$myclass->execute();` at each level to cascade the call.

Comment: Yeah you are right ! i am thinking about appending callbacks to an array but i need to keep the hierarchical structure then loop and call.

Comment: @lotfio, can you show us the data before you are trying to put it in `MyClass`? What should the output look like? Can you show more than one example?